# typescript method returning undefined?

Tags: typescript, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Hi I have an angular 5 application. I have a service method that returns undefined . 
here is what i am trying to do . i have a function named cloneFlight. i am making a call to flightsService.getCampaignsToClone(this.flight) which is returning value undefined .

```
cloneFlight() {
    combineLatest(
      this.translateService.get('CONFIRM.CLONE_FLIGHT', { item: this.flight.name}),
      this.flightsService.getCampaignsToClone(this.flight)
    ).subscribe( ([header, campaigns]) => { 
      this.cloneFlightService.openModal(header,this.flight,campaigns);
    });
  }
```

the code for getCampaignsToClone  is as follows.

```
 getCampaignsToClone(flight: Flight){

    let campaignStatusesIdArr: string[];
    let campaigns: CampaignUnpaginated[] ; 
    this.campaignService.getStatuses().subscribe(
      (data) => { 
        campaignStatusesIdArr = data.filter( x => x.code === (CampaignStatusCode.IN_PROGRESS || 
          CampaignStatusCode.READY)).map( y => y.id);
      }
    );
    let accountId: string = flight.campaign.account.id;    

    this.campaignService.getUnpaginatedCampaigns(
      {
        statuses: campaignStatusesIdArr,
        accounts: accountId
      }
    ).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      campaigns = data;
    });
    return Observable.of(campaigns);
  }
```

in getCampaignsToClone i am making an http call  campaignService.getStatuses() that returns Observable . then filtering out some of them and then i make a call to 
getUnpaginatedCampaigns which is another http call. anyidea what is the best way to write this code so that the method wont return undefined. I think i am probably not utilising the rxjs operators. could someone help me to figure it out .

thank you so much

Comment: Its the typical async call problem where you only have access to values inside of the subscribe not outside

Comment: Why in `getCampaignsToClone` are you *subscribing* to an observable that contains the data you want, then returning a *different* observable of a variable that hasn't actually been assigned to yet? I'd recommend writing a test for `getCampaignsToClone` to check it actually returns an observable of the data you want *before* trying to then consume it alongside other observables. It looks like you probably just want to `return this.campaignService.getUnpaginatedCampaigns(...)`.

Comment: that is right jonrsharpe i just want to return campaigns: CampaignUnpaginated[] . i am newbie to rx js couldnt figure it out what is the best way to right .thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your `getCampaignsToClone` method so it returns an Observable sequence. Use flatMap to subscribe to the getUnpaginatedCampaigns observable in turn.

```
getCampaignsToClone(flight: Flight): Observable<CampaignUnpaginated[]> {
 return this.campaignService.getStatuses().pipe(
    map(data => data.filter( x => x.code === (CampaignStatusCode.IN_PROGRESS || CampaignStatusCode.READY)).map(x => x.id)),
    flatMap(ids => this.campaignService.getUnpaginatedCampaigns({
        statuses: ids,
        accounts: flight.campaign.account.id,
    }))
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you jesse it works !!!!! could you explain this a bit more . i think the input to the flatmap is a stream of campaign status and what does the flatmap do ???

Comment: FlatMap expects an observable, but does not subscribe to it right away. When you subscribe to the getCampainsToClone observable, first you subscribe to the getStatuses observable. Next step: filter and map the results. Then you encounter the flatMap, now you subscribe to it. It's the rxjs way do async stuff in a certain order. Read more: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html